# How to build opencascade doc as single pdf?

Tags: pdf-generation, doc, opencascade

I found a pdf here:

```
https://documentation.help/Open-Cascade/documentation.pdf
```

which contains all docs in a single pdf,but it is for OCC 7.2,and a utility class .gendoc which comes with occt source,but no instructions about it ,question is:

```
 How to build opencascade doc as single pdf like above link?
```

Thank in advance!!!

Comment: `gendoc` has an option `-chm` generating a single `occt_overview.chm` that you can find within each OCCT release. However, the option `-pdf` generates several PDF files (`occt_tutorial.pdf`, `occt_step.pdf` and others), so I guess you need to patch `gendoc` to make a single PDF.

Comment: @gkv311 thanks,I tried to run " ./gendoc -chm -overview" but just get a bunch of erors,How and where do you run gendoc?

Comment: Documentation generator requires several tools being configuring in PATH like Doxygen and others (I've generated only HTML so far): https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt_contribution__documentation.html